# The Ranger file manager for Linux hangs with just "loading...ranger"

Tags: linux, ls

When I run Ranger, it prints its standard message:

```
loading...ranger
```

But then hangs forever.  What is the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a **broken mount point** or similar system directory issue.  Verify with this command:

```
ls /
```

If that also hangs, it's your system, **not Ranger at issue**.  Review the mounts on your system until `ls /` works and Ranger should be fine.